# Cloud function authorization vs validationHandler

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Found myself opening a couple of functions for access to users with invalid session tokens. The only way I could find to do that is to intercept the request using a bodyParser before Parse gets the request and removing sessionToken from the request.

Now trying to do a better job managing authorization to all functions - My question are:

1. can I relax the requirement that if a sessionToken is included it must be valid in any other way? Is session token validation done using a default validationHandler that can be replaced or is that done elsewhere?
2. to control access to cloud functions, is there anything like ACL roles? does cloud function's "validationHandler" accept only param? or can I inspect the user object as well?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. In parse-server you can make sure that the sessions are valid because if you will try to run any CRUD operation with invalid session you will get http 403 error that your session is not valid or expired. You can control on the "Length" of your session by changing the **sessionLength** property in your parse-server app. The default is 1 year
2. There is no control access to cloud functions but you can check if a logged in user trigger this function by checking if the **request.user** is not undefined.  Cloud functions can get only params in key-value pairs and those params cannot be Parse Objects. if you want to send ParseObject you can send the **objectId** of the parse object and then query for it in cloud code to get the full object. You can always access the user context in **request.user** (only if cloud code was triggered by the user). If you still want to "protect" your cloud code you can check if the calling user have a Role by query the Role DB and check if the user is  contained there.

Comment: Thanks Ran, Maybe I should be more clear - 1) I was actually asking if there is a way to allow invalid tokens access to my cloud code function. The reason I ask this is because some functions are free to unauthenticated users to access. However, if a user has a stale session in his request, he will be refused. The workaround I found for this is intercepting the request before parse server receives it - and deleting any session token if passed to these public requests. only then can I ensure that parse will process the requests. But I was hoping there is a better way.

Comment: 2) There are some access rules I need to enforce - I don't rely only on ACL for authorization. So I need another authorization mechanism. But validationHandler receives only the params, and not the request.user. What I need is to run generic code to match each request's params with the user's privileges. So I need something similar to validationHandler, only that has access also to the user object. Again, I can probably do that by wrapping each function handler with an authorization check handler function - but if I can instead register authorization check functions - that would be better

Comment: It is possible for you to send the user object id from the client and then read it in cloud code?

Comment: I can do that - but then it's not authenticated. I must access the request.user object for this to have any value from authentication point of view. Otherwise, anyone can create a user in my app, and use it to call functions that access other users.